# Efficient way to call a plugin on a DOM element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am consuming [intl-tel-inut](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input) plugin in my registration form.

Here is my code:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    var iti = $("#Phone").intlTelInput({
        allowDropdown: false,
        autoHideDialCode: true,
        autoPlaceholder: "off",
        onlyCountries: ['bd'],
        utilsScript: "/Scripts/utils.js",
    });

    $('#Phone').on('blur', function () {

        // here, the index maps to the error code returned from getValidationError - see readme
        var errorMap = ["Invalid number", "Invalid country code", "Too short", "Too long", "Invalid number"];

        var element = $('[data-valmsg-for="Phone"]');

        if ($('#Phone').val().trim()) {
            if ($("#Phone").intlTelInput('isValidNumber')) {
                element.removeClass("field-validation-error");
                element.addClass("field-validation-valid");
                element.html('');

                var num = $("#Phone").intlTelInput('getNumber');
            } else {
                element.removeClass("field-validation-valid");
                element.addClass("field-validation-error");

                messageElement = $(document.createElement("span"));
                messageElement.attr('id', 'Phone-error');
                element.append(messageElement);

                var errorCode = $("#Phone").intlTelInput('getValidationError');
                messageElement.html(errorMap[errorCode]);
            }
        }
    });        
});
```

Here I need to call `$("#Phone").intlTelInput()` whenever I need to call any method from the plugin.

I tried `iti.isValidNumber()` [iti is local variable I created], but it gives me error. So, every time I need to call `$("#Phone").intlTelInput('isValidNumber'))`. Is there no efficient way to call the variable and call a method with dot systax.

I need to call 'getNumber' method and it's can be called in the same way -  `var num = $("#Phone").intlTelInput('getNumber')`

But I need to pass a parameter through the 'getNumber' method and I can't find a way to do it. Can you please tell me how to pass parameter in this way?

Comment: If `iti` is instance of plugin and that plugin does not exposes it's *private* methods, then you can't call it with *dot notation* unless you write your own wrappers around plugin that has setters and getters. What's wrong with calling `.intlTelInput('isValidNumber')` instead of `.isValidNumber()`?

Comment: Faced no problem while there is no parameters, but if I need to pass parameters, how should I do that with $("#Phone").intlTelInput('getNumber')?

Comment: Check documentation under `customPlaceholder`: `.intlTelInput(input, paramsObject)`